# jdom 2.0.5 XML-Parsing error: not well formed

Tags: xml, utf-8, jdom

I have some problems by opening/ loading a generated xml-file because it's not well formed ("Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence").
I already searched for some solutions and changed my code for getting the design as following:

```
System.out.println("Which Design-File shall be modified? Please enter: [file].xml");

    String file = "file.xml";

    // generate JDOM Document
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
     try {
        // getting rid of the UTF8 problem when reading the modified xml file
        InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(file)          
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");

        InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
        is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        Document doc = builder.build(is);
     } 
     catch (JDOMException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } 
     catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

after changing the design, I write it with the XMLOutputter as followed:

```
    String fileNew = "file_modified.xml";
    FileWriter writer;
    try {
        Format format = Format.getPrettyFormat();
        format.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        writer = new FileWriter(fileNew);
        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(format);
        outputter.output(doc, writer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Does somebody has a solution for my problem? I really thought that these codelines would be solve my problem, but when I load it into the firefox it still says that it's not well formed :/.

Answer (score 1):

From the [XMLOutputter documentation](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html):

> **Warning:** When outputting to a `Writer`, make sure the writer's encoding
>   matches the encoding setting in the Format object. This ensures the
>   encoding in which the content is written (controlled by the `Writer`
>   configuration) matches the encoding placed in the document's XML
>   declaration (controlled by the `XMLOutputter`). Because a `Writer` cannot
>   be queried for its encoding, the information must be passed to the
>   Format manually in its constructor or via the
>   `Format.setEncoding(java.lang.String)` method. The default encoding is
>   UTF-8.

JDOM uses the encoding of the Format instance to determine the encoding used for OutputStreams though, so, the recommended way to write your code is:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileNew)) {
    Format format = Format.getPrettyFormat();
    format.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(format);
    outputter.output(doc, fos);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Using OutputStreams instead of Writers will ensure that the actual encoding used is applied to the file, instead of the platform default.